# RAILS-4 Resque Worker in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, resque

I have a rails project in production who use active jobs with resque.
My redis server is on the same server of the website.
Often my resque workers crash and cause many problemes.

I start my workers like this :

```
RAILS_ENV=production QUEUE=* rake environment resque:work > worker.log &
disown %1
```

I figure this is not the best way to work..

Is there a better way to process?
When my workers are starting, everything works fine!

Comment: Does your server have enough capacity to run all these?

Comment: It's a 2gb memory, 2 coreprocessor, 40gb ssd, it's to small you think?